# github won't permit me to use my ssh key

Tags: ssh, github, ssh-keys

I am trying to config my github account. However, I keep getting this error and for the life me cannot figure why. I have added my ssh key to github and I am sure that the ssh key is in the directory ~/.ssh/id_rsa. I don't know what else to do..

```
skline-mac:first_app skline$ sudo ssh -v  git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /var/root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
skline-mac:first_app skline$
```

Comment: Did you added the rsa key to the local machine cache?

Comment: I probably did not, I am new to all of this. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drop the sudo from your command. It's trying to load root's keys, not yours.

Comment: how do I get to the root keys

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Right now you are running this command: 'sudo ssh -v  git@github.com'. Drop the sudo. Just run 'ssh git@github.com'